# Javascript align vertical center many child divs within parent

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to dynamically resize the div (col with pad) with JavaScript so that it is vertically middle of the parent div (row).
The text blocks vary in size as do the images and there are many of these divs within the page.
I'm quite close to achieving this with the provided code, but the loop seems to be repeating more times than it should and sets the height incorrectly on the last pass, almost like it is halving the space over and over again.
Is there a way to make the JavaScript only run once?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col pad">
  <p>Text here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>
</div>  

$(window).load(function(){
  $('.row').each(function() {
    var parentDiv = $(this).height();
    $('.pad').each(function() {
      var childDiv = $(this).height();
      var space = parentDiv - childDiv;
      var half = space/2;
      $(this).css('paddingTop', half + 'px');
      alert(half);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm unable to use css to achieve this as col are floated.

Comment: in css you could try `margin: auto` to center a block-element in a block-element. can you provide that as a jsfiddle, so we can try out the code?

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/charlesdarwin/19q6eqz4/24/ You may need to resize the window so that the divs are side by side and then re-run the fiddle.